# Sort sales by year and client name and pick only the top N in each year

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df like this:

| date | client_name | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | A | 1500 |
| 2019-01-01 | B | 2500 |
| 2019-01-01 | C | 4000 |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 5000 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Originally, the df had daily data. After resampling into yearly data, I used groupby to group by date and client_name.

`df.groupby(['date','client_name'])['sales'].sum()`

| date | client_name | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | A | 1,500 |
|  | B | 2,500 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 5,000 |
|  | B | 10,000 |

There are two issues I have been trying to solve:

1. I need sales sorted by year and sales value (both in descending order)
2. I only need the top 10 clients in each year.

The output would be something like this:

| date | client_name | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | A | 2,500 |
|  | B | 1,500 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 10,000 |
|  | B | 5,000 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I tried a few approaches, including:
`df.sort_values('sales',ascending = False).groupby(['date', 'client_name'])['sales'].sum().head(10)`

but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas of how to solve this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the year and use it to groupby:

```
N = 2
(df
 .sort_values(by='sales', ascending=False)
 .groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year, 'client_name'])
 .head(N)
)
```

output:

```
         date client_name  sales
3  2020-01-01           A   5000
2  2019-01-01           C   4000
1  2019-01-01           B   2500
0  2019-01-01           A   1500
```

Another method to extract the year from a YYYY-MM-DD string:

```
df['date'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False)
```

##### alternative sorting

```
N = 2
(df
 .sort_values(by=['client_name', 'sales'], ascending=[True, False])
 .groupby(['client_name', pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year])
 .head(N)
)
```

output:

```
         date client_name  sales
3  2020-01-01           A   5000
0  2019-01-01           A   1500
1  2019-01-01           B   2500
2  2019-01-01           C   4000
```